# NAnt - The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Tags: mercurial, ssl-certificate, nant, self-signed

Using NAnt, I'm trying to download a file from my Mercurial server via my build script.

The Mercurial server is configured to allow access via https using a self-signed certificate.

I'm able to download the file without issues using a web browser, so I know the permissions on the server are set properly.

When I try to do this via NAnt however, I get an error stating 'The remote connection is invalid according to the validation procedure.'.

Can anyone offer suggestions as to how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server's certificate needs to be installed on the machine executing the script in order for this to work.

See this [procedure](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841.aspx#BKMK_addlocal) for instructions on how to do this. You'll need to export the certificate from the server before starting. This can be done by viewing the website's certificate details in your browser and exporting them.